# GCM between User to User from same Android App

Tags: android, mysql, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to implement GCM in my Android app:

1. One Android app
2. Registered- U_user and another M_user.

I have Google Sign In in my app thats works fine with JSON and GSON and local MySQL database server with `tomcat-server restutil` to keep storing Gmail login users.

So, I want to send a notification from U_user to M_user.

U_user does a registration that has been pushed to M_user.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean the same Android app installed on different phones (U_user's phone and a separate phone for M_user).

To quote a section in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#unreg-why):

> To make sure that messages go to the intended user:
>
> 1. Your app server can maintain a mapping between the current user and the registration ID.
> 2. The app can then check to ensure that messages it receives match the logged in user.

What this means is that you can send messages to another user through GCM. To let the app server know what to send to M_user, let U_user send an upstream message to your GCM app server (only possible in app servers using XMPP - see [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html)). Alternatively, you have the option to do POST requests to your app server via `HttpUrlConnection` (can work on both XMPP- and HTTP-based GCM app servers).

Regardless of which method you use, specify in these messages to the server that you would like to send a message to M_user.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! let me try that and i'll come back ya